# Saving plot as multiple file types

Tags: r

I have a heatmap I want to save as a PDF, TIFF, and EPS. Is there a more efficient way to doing such as opposed to the following:

```
setEPS()
postscript(...)
heatmap(...)
dev.off()
pdf(...)
heatmap(...)
dev.off()
tiff(...)
heatmap(...)
dev.off()
```

Comment: I don't think so. This is what I'd do.

Comment: You can write a function to do this in case you have many plots to make.

Comment: If you're on Windows, you can use `savePlot` multiple times on the same active plot.

Comment: Thanks @Roland, I'll go with this then